# SQL Server Update Indexing Design

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I got a table, IDMAP with DML:

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb2.dbo.idmaptemp (
    OldId varchar(20),
    CV_ModStamp datetimeoffset,
    NewId varchar(20),
    RestoreComplete bit,
    RestoreErrorMessage varchar(1000),
    OperationType varchar(20)
)
```

As it is defined, it already contains a predefined set of rows about (1Million). When restore operation is complete, I have to update NewId, RestoreComplete, RestoreErrorMessage on the table.
The statement is:

```
update tempdb2.dbo.IdMaptemp set NewId = 'xxx', RestoreComplete = 'false', RestoreErrorMessage = 'error' where OldId = 'ABC';
```

The Java application has about a million values on memory and has to update the values with the above statement. The database is set to autocommit off and is varied with batch (batchsize 500).

I have tried two options on Indexing with OldId field:

1. Clustered Index  - Execution plan lists as clustered index update (100% cost). This occurs as the leaves are the rows that are getting updated and which would trigger an index update. Am I right here?
2. Non-Clustered Index - Execution plan lists as update (75%) and seek(25%).

Are there any other speed ups that can be achieved on mass update on a database table? The table cannot be cleared and re-inserted as there are other rows that aren't affected by the updates. Clustered index on a sample of 500 rows per batch has taken around 7 hours to update.

Should I go for the Non-Clustered index option?

Comment: The percentages are meaningless, they just indicate how the cost is distributed in the plan, they don't have any value outside of the plan.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Any info that can be found which phase takes time on the execution plan?

Comment: If you are troubleshooting performance, perhaps you could move the update out of Java and into a SQL script. Are you running 1 million individual update statements against this table? If so, you might find a large proportion of the performance issue is due to individual update statements rather than any particular index. If you could refactor your process to perform all these operations in the database it would be quicker. For example, bulk load a million values into another table and then perform an in database update in one batch.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I understand that the approach of doing in the database layer is faster. Speaking from an application developer pov, if there are several tables that vary in update fields, should I be writing code for every table? This doesn't seem to be robust though making database to do the legwork seems to be appropriate. Wish there was a utility or a driver that handles mass updates with the temp table approach!

Comment: I don't see the difference between writing code for every table in your Java app or in the database. Perhaps you have some dynamic code in your Java app. Writing non dynamic code in the database can enable certain performance improvements. Anyway the real question is where do these million data points in your Java app come from? Do they come from another database or can they be generated in a database? If your data is making a round trip from DB>Java>DB then it seems to me you have a good opportunity for performance improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a large table's clustered index is an expensive proposition.  A table's clustered index is defined for the entire table and not for a subset of rows.

If you're leaving `oldid` as the clustered index and just want to improve the batching performance, consider allowing the db to participate in the batching process rather than the application/java layer. Asking the db to update millions of rows 1 row at a time, is an expensive proposition. Populating a temp table with batches worth and then letting SQL update the entire batch at a time can be a good way of improving performance.

```
insert #temptable (OldId,NewId)
...

Update
set T1.NewId = T2.NewId
T1
from
T1 join #tempTable T2
on T1.OldId = T2.OldId
```

If you can compute the new id, consider another batching tactic.

```
update tempdb2.dbo.IdMaptemp top 1000 set NewId = 'xxx', RestoreComplete = 'false', 
    RestoreErrorMessage = 'error' where NewId is null;
```

If you really want to create a new table with NewId as the clustered index
Create the new table as you like

```
insert into NewTable()
select top 10000 *
from OldTable O
left join NewTable N
on O.OldId = N.OldId
where N.OldId is null
```

When done, drop the old table.

Note: Does your id need to be 20 bytes? Typically clustered indexes are either int - 4 bytes or bigint - 8 bytes.

If this is a one time thing, then changing the clustered index on a large persistent table will be worth it.  If the oldid though will always be in the process of acquiring the newid value, and that's just the workflow you have, I wouldn't bother changing the persistent table's clustered index.  Just leave the oldid as the clustered index.  NewId sounds like a surrogate key.

Comment: The indexes on the table can be modified while creation as this is a temporary table. Eventually, the status is written to the data source table by joining with the new id. This seems to be a never ending cycle with updating a large set of values on the database. Does the table still need an index since updates are run on joins? Reg. the ids, the ids are uniquely generated 20 chars and is specific to the requirements.

Comment: Again.. I suspect this is an operation that can take place completely in the database and it's just being done in Java because that's the hammer you like to use.... I could be wrong but it happens a lot!